# How to create script to change audio device in SIP Phone on Windows 7

Tags: audio, script, bluetooth, microphone

I hope I am posting in the right place, if there is somewhere more suitable, please point me in the right direction!

Here is the picture describing what I want to accomplish with a hotkey or a shortcut:

[image]

I have a soft phone software Aspect SIP Phone 1.0 version 2.5 Prof build 49393, by . that is used for my job in taking calls from customer in tech support.

I have a Bluetooth wireless headset, which I use for taking these calls. However, when the mic activates, the sound quality from other channels drop significantly, due to the nature of bluetooth connection.

Therefore, when I take a call, I want a quick way to activate the mic in the software (I.e select it in the device options for the program), and then quickly be able to disable the mic for listening to music or the like.

I am attaching a screenshot which I hope illustrates what I wish to accomplish. Basically, I want to create a hotkey or shortcut for switching between 5 and 6 on the screenshot, allowing me to choose the Plantronics device or the Sennheiser device quickly.

Being a total beginner in creating scripts of any kind, please describe in detail how to proceed if there is a way to fix this.

If anyone could assist me in doing this, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is more a question for the application developer (Aspect), applications generally do not have a command line for this kind of granularity and a hotkey change would have to be something built into the program. My question would be why does the quality drop so much when your BT headset is active, I use one all the time and don't have this issue with "sound quality from other channels"?

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Basically, when I use the headset actively (talking to someone on the phone) the sound quality from the phone call itself is perfectly fine. But if I have spotify running in the back with some music, that quality will be low. Same with system sounds from windows. As I've understood it from Plantronics, this is 'the way Bluetooth works'. Once I deactivate the mic from the phone device, by selecting another mic device, then the sound quality from spotify and other sources are 100% again. Activating the mic again, it drops. Would appreciate any insight into this as well!